# LMEM: Chi-square = 0 , prob = 1 - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: r, anova, lme4

I'm running a LMEM (linear mixed effects model) on some data, and compare the models (in pairs) with the anova function. However, on a particular subset of data, I'm getting nonsense results.

This is my full model:

```
m3_full <- lmer(totfix ~ psource + cond + psource:cond + 
  1 + cond | subj) + (1 + psource + cond | object), data, REML=FALSE)
```

And this is the model I'm comparing it to: (basically dropping out one of the main effects)

```
m3_psource <- lmer (totfix ~ psource + cond + psource:cond - 
 psource + (1 + cond | subj) + (1 + psource + cond | object), 
  data, REML=FALSE)
```

Running the `anova()` function (`anova(m3_full, m3_psource)` returns Chisq = 0, pr>(Chisq) = 1

I'm doing the same for a few other LMEMs and everything seems fine, it's just this particular response value that gives me the weird chi-square and probability values. Anyone has an idea why and how I can fix it? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a mixed-model-specific question: rather, it has to do with the way that R constructs model matrices from formulas (and, possibly, with the logic of your model comparison).

Let's narrow it down to the comparison between

```
form1 <- ~ psource + cond + psource:cond
```

and

```
form2 <- ~ psource + cond + psource:cond - psource
```

(which is equivalent to `~cond + psource:cond`). These two formulas give **equivalent** model matrices, i.e. model matrices with the same number of columns, spanning the same design space, and giving the same overall goodness of fit.

Making up a minimal data set to explore:

```
dd <- expand.grid(psource=c("A","B"),cond=c("a","b"))
```

What constructed variables do we get with each formula?

```
colnames(model.matrix(form1,data=dd))
## [1] "(Intercept)"    "psourceB"       "condb"          "psourceB:condb"

colnames(model.matrix(form2,data=dd))
## [1] "(Intercept)"    "condb"          "psourceB:conda" "psourceB:condb"
```

We get the same number of contrasts.

There are two possible responses to this problem.

1. There is one school of thought (typified by Nelder, Venables, etc.: e.g. see Venables' famous (?) but unpublished [exegeses on linear models](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS3/Exegeses.pdf), section 5, or Wikipedia on the [principle of marginality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_marginality)) that says that it doesn't make sense to try to test main effects in the presence of interaction terms, which is what you're trying to do.
2. There are *occasional* situations (e.g in a before-after-control-impact design where the 'before' difference between control and impact is known to be zero due to experimental protocol) where you really do want to do this comparison. In this case, you have to make up your own dummy variables and add them to your data, e.g.

```
## set up model matrix and drop intercept and "psourceB" column
dummies <- model.matrix(form1,data=dd)[,-(1:2)]
## d='dummy': avoid colons in column names
colnames(dummies) <- c("d_cond","d_source_by_cond")
colnames(model.matrix(~d_cond+d_source_by_cond,data.frame(dd,dummies)))
## [1] "(Intercept)"      "d_cond"           "d_source_by_cond"
```

This is a nuisance. My guess at the reason for this being difficult is that the original authors of R and S before it were from school of thought #1, and figured that generally when people were trying to do this it was a mistake; they didn't make it impossible, but they didn't go out of their way to make it easy.

Comment: Thanks! When I'm comparing two other models (without one main effect vs full one) for a different response variable from the same dataset, I don't get the same problem (chisq & probabilities are normal). I get the chisq=0 and prob=1 when I take out any main effect, and when comparing to a model with only the random effects, and only for the response variable 'totfix'. I should've also added that I've done deviation coding on the 'psource' and 'cond' factors (don't know how relevant this is). Any idea why this might be? I'll try the dummy coding, though, hopefully it'll fix the issue!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure without going into more detail.  The first sentence of your comment is somewhat surprising though ... according to my argument, should depend only on predictor variables  (numeric vs factor, main vs interaction).  *If* you code your interaction manually, or base it on numeric input variables, I would think it should work. (But do keep the idea outlined in point #1 above in mind ...)